# Xamarin forms: Why Popupimage showing 2 times?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, popup

I am using `Rg.Plugins.Popup`(1.1.4.129-beta) for showing `popupimage`. I am using the following code for showing `popuppage`.

```
await PopupNavigation.Instance.PushAsync(new UploadImagePopupPage(imagepath), true);
```

**My Issue**

Sometimes popup showing 2 times.

**Issues scenario**

First I call the `popupimage` like below from one `contentpage`.

```
//Checking one condition
if (_images.Count != 0)
{
   await PopupNavigation.Instance.PushAsync(new UploadImagePopupPage(picturepath), true);
}
```

In `UploadImagePopupPage` added following code for showing the image:

```
popupimage.Source = picturepath;
```

Then from the `UploadImagePopupPage` I send a message like below when clicking a button. As a result, the next image in the `observablecollection` will show as the popup.

```
MessagingCenter.Send<UploadImagePopupPage>(this, "complete");
```

Then again call the `popupimage` from the initial page like following:

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<UploadImagePopupPage>(this, "complete", (sender) =>
{
   ShowImagePopUp();
});

public async void ShowImagePopUp()
    {
        try
        {
            //Removing current popup
            await PopupNavigation.Instance.PopAsync();

             //Checking one condition
            if (Utility.picturecount < _images.Count)
            {
               // Following popup code invoking 2 times
                await PopupNavigation.Instance.PushAsync(new UploadImagePopupPage(_images[Utility.picturecount]), true);
            }
            else
            {
                _images.Clear();
                await Navigation.PopModalAsync();
            }
            Utility.loadPhotoAlbum = true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Exception:>>"+e);
        }
    }
```

I implemented this to show the `observablecollection` images one by one as `popup`. There is a button in the popuppage, and when clicking that button only the next popup will come. Does anyone face this type of issue?

Comment: So you are receiving 2 complete messages and the code invokes twice?

Comment: I'm guessing your problem is the double tap on a button is invoking the send message twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to unsubscribe the event in `OnDisappearing`

```
protected override void OnDisappearing() 
{ 
    base.OnDisappearing(); 

    MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<UploadImagePopupPage>(this, "complete"); 
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but no luck. I am sure there is no double tab.

Comment: Inside of the if condition, I already add comment there, 
Following popup code invoking 2 times
await PopupNavigation.Instance.PushAsync(new UploadImagePopupPage(_images[Utility.picturecount]), true);
            }

Comment: Yes, however, for the code to be executed there twice, the method should be called twice. Have you checked that?

Comment: Yes method is calling 2 times, could be the issue of multi subscriptions of MessagingCenter. Is it possible to restrict the multi subscriptions of MessagingCenter?

Comment: Code mistake in the OnDisappearing().

Comment: protected override void OnDisappearing()
        {
            base.OnDisappearing();
            MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<UploadImagePopupPage>(this, "complete");
        }

Comment: When add the above lines my issue get resolved, can you please post it as your answer?